# scrapy outputs empty csv

Tags: python, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

I have been trying to use scrapy with python to scrape craigslist posts.
The code is originally from Tsung Hung.

My spider code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_craigslist.items import ScrapyCraigslistItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'craigslist'
    allowed_domains = ['sfbay.craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?']

rules = (
    Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(
        allow=(r'sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa.*'),
        deny = (r'.*format\=rss.*')
    ),
        callback="parse_items_1",
        follow= True,
         ),
    )


def parse_items_1(self, response):

    self.logger.info('You are now crawling: %s', response.url)
    items = []
    hxs = Selector(response)
    contents = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='rows']/*")
    for content in contents:
        item = ScrapyCraigslistItem()
        item ["title"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/a/span/text()").extract()[0]
        k = content.xpath("//p/a/@href").extract()[0]
        item ['ad_url'] = 'https://sfbay.craigslist.org{}'.format(''.join(k))
        item ["post_date"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/time/text()").extract()[0]
        item ["post_date_specific"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span/time/@datetime").extract()[0]
        item ["price"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span[@class='l2']/span/text()").extract()[0]
        item ["location"] = content.xpath("//p/span/span[@class='l2']/span[@class='pnr']/small/text()").extract()[0].strip()
    return items
```

My items file looks like:

```
import scrapy

class ScrapyCraigslistItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    post_date = scrapy.Field()
    post_date_specific = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    ad_url = scrapy.Field()
```

I don't get any error messages in terminal when I try to run, but my csv file when I run "scrapy crawl craigslist -o output.csv" is just empty.

Comment: The rules are defined in such a way that they match no url on the start url, resulting in no items. Try `scrapy crawl craigslist -o output.csv -L DEBUG` and I think you won't see `You are now crawling: <some url>` in the logs.

Comment: The odd thing is that I think the scraper is working in that it at least combs through many different craigslist posts. For some reason I feel as though it isn't returning the right value to be written in the CSV file. My terminal output does end up displaying many columns of: 2017-04-14 08:45:44 [craigslist] INFO: You are now crawling: https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/apa?sale_date=2017-04-16&sort=upcoming

Comment: That's weird. Running it on my machine doesn't give me such logging. Anyway, I think you need to yield item at the end of your for loop. Returning items seems to do nothing as your code does not put any value in this variable.

Comment: I see many problems here, starting with the extractors that do not work. The site has changed since Hung Tsung has created the spider?
Anyway, you forgot the instruction "items.append(item)" in the parse_items_1 method before "return items".